# "Native code library failed to load" outside of IDE when running exported .jar

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface, executable-jar

as stated in the title, my programm won't start outside of Eclipse. I've imported a library consisting of a xy.jar and xy_jni.dll

CMD within the folder of the jar-file:

```
java -jar myprogramm.jar
```

is followed by the statement:

`"Native code library failed to load. Please add the xy-folder as location for native libraries. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xy_jni in java.library.path`

It doesn't matter if I click extract or package ressources when exporting the jar-file.

Also under `Project-Settings, Java Build Path, Libraries` the .jar & xy_jni(.dll) is added and within all the expandables in libraries the "xy-folder" is set as "Native library location". Also under Libraries I added a "Add Library" named "xy-folder" inhibiting the .jar & xy_jni.dll

When opening the final exported jar-file with a file viewer the xy-folder is included with the xy_jni.dll only, the xy.jar is in the root folder.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to distribute `dll/so/dylib` within `jar` file. The reason here is that you depend on system when it comes to loading libraries.

Typically, libraries have to lay around, somewhere on the file system. This way, they are loaded by `System.load` and `System.loadLibrary`.

You can use simple solution to solve this issue. All you have to do, is to extract your native code to some location and load it from there.

Take a look here for a full sample related to loading libraries from `JAR`:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo035

Comment: As stated in your first and third paragraph, I managed after cleaning the project and files within eclipse to order dependencies in such way that the exported jar can find these. Nevertheless the .dll had to be in external location of the jar to run properly.